# Python Requests Tableau REST API SSL Errors

Tags: python, rest, ssl, tableau-api

I'm not overly familiar with how certs work, so I'm probably doing something dumb, apologies in advance.

I'm attempting to interact with tableau's rest API and do so using a secure connection, as some of their calls require this.

However, I'm running into various errors creating a connection.

I am able to create a insecure connection:

```
requests.get('https://tableau.mynetwork.lan', verify = False)
<Response [200]>
```

I am also able to create a secure connection with google:

```
requests.get('https://google.com', verify = True)
<Response [200]>
```

However, attempting to create a secure connection with my tableau server:

```
requests.get('https://tableau.mynetwork.lan', verify = True)
```

or:

```
requests.get('https://tableau.mynetwork.lan', verify = certifi.old_where())
```

Results in the following error:

```
SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
```

I have my tableau server certs on my local machine, and have attempted to pass them via the cert parameter:

```
tableau_cert = r"C:\tabcert.cer"
requests.get('https://tableau.mynetwork.lan', cert=tableau_cert, verify = True)
```

But get this error:

```
Error: [('PEM routines', 'PEM_read_bio', 'no start line'), ('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file', 'PEM lib')]
```

Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

> I have my tableau server certs on my local machine, and have attempted to pass them via the cert parameter:
>
> ```
> requests.get('https://tableau.mynetwork.lan', cert=tableau_cert, verify = True)
> ```

`cert` is the wrong parameter to to specify the CA. The correct way [according to the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) is to set the path to your CA file as the value of the `verify` parameter:

```
requests.get('https://tableau.mynetwork.lan', verify=tableau_cert)
```

Also, make sure that the file you have is properly [PEM encoded](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file).